# How to determine membership of user in well-known-groups as Everyone

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, access-token

In my current job I need to enumerate members of well-known-groups in Windows, as Everyone, Interactive User, etc. I can find some "according to me" definitions how to estimate is user is member of Everyone, but it's much harder to get that info for other groups. I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379554(v=vs.85).aspx which does what I need, well almost, because I would need to get user access-token without login him/her in (because I do not know her/his password). Is it possible to get something like access token without login user in? And I'd like to solve it without .NET.

Comment: Is this a local user or an AD user?

Comment: @Benj: That would be a second question, for each user that's a member of the `Everyone` group.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone, Interactive Users, Authenticated Users are not really groups. They are SIDs which appear in your token, but you are not a member of them.

Instead the attribute gets added to your token if you are authenticated, if you are interactive, and so on. So the same user can connect via the network, and their token will not have Interactive Users in it. But if they log on via terminal services, their token WILL have Interactive Users.

You can see from this example that **these pseudo-groups are not attributes of the user, but of the logon session**. Therefore you cannot enumerate users with that attribute.

Comment: And thus everyone will get the `Everyone` SID added to their token, except for anonymous tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look to [this URL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10042/The-Windows-Access-Control-Model-Part-1). This is a really good serie of articles about SID, Groups, membership, etc...with samples in C++.